# Is this correct behavior of template?

Tags: c++, templates

```
template<class blah, class bleh>
blah func(bleh p)
{
    // Do something
}

int main()
{
    double d=1.111;
    int i = func<int>(d); // #1
    int j = func<int,double>(d); // #2
    // ....
}
```

In this example both the instances of `func`, #1 and #2 are compiling, but I'm unsure of what is correct, and why.

Can some one explain why #1 is correct, and maybe give some background?

Comment: #1 uses type deduction, [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction). So the compiler sees `d` as a double and deduces `bleh` should be a double.

Comment: #1 uses type deduction from the given parameter.

Comment: Niall and πάντα added everything you need to know. That's the main difference between the two approaches.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, *this is correct behaviour*.

### Case 1 - type deduction

```
func<int>(d);
```

This uses [template type deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) to determine the type for `bleh`.

> In order to instantiate a function template, every template argument must be known, but not every template argument has to be specified. **When possible, the compiler will deduce the missing template arguments from the function arguments**. This occurs when a function call is attempted and when an address of a function template is taken.

The compiler sees the type for `d` as being a `double` and thus deduces the actual type for `bleh` must also be a `double`.

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction), also covered in § 14.8.2 of the C++ specification;

> Template argument deduction attempts to determine template arguments ..., **which can be substituted into each parameter `P` to produce the type deduced `A`**, which is the same as the type of the argument `A`, ... .
>
> If there are multiple parameters, each `P`/`A` pair is deduced separately and the deduced template arguments are then combined. If deduction fails or is ambiguous for any `P`/`A` pair or if different pairs yield different deduced template arguments, or if any template argument remains neither deduced nor explicitly specified, compilation fails.

### Case 2

```
func<int,double>(d);
```

The type for `bleh` is explicitly set to `double`, hence the compiler will make it such. The argument `d` is provided and since it is also a `double`, the compiler happily continues. If an argument (i.e. in place of `d`) was provided with a type that was not a `double`, or could not implicitly be converted to a `double` (e.g. via promotions, non-explicit constructors or user provided conversions), this would result in an error.

Comment: Which means that `int j = func<int,int>(d);` is also OK but since `p` is an `int` in this call, you may get different results.